# How to set increment value for Y axis in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I need to change increment value for Y axis.

I'm using this code to set min and max:

```
YAxis rightYAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
rightYAxis.setAxisMaxValue(180);
rightYAxis.setAxisMinValue(0);
```

It gives me this view of the right Y axis:

[image: View of the chart]

Y axis shows [0, 30, 60, ..., 180] so increment here is 30. But I need to set increment equal 10. So I want to see [0, 10, 20, ..., 180].

I thought that `mChart.setVisibleYRange(10, YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);` will help me, but it didn't. The same for `rightYAxis.mAxisRange = 10;`.

Is it possible to set it up? It would be very useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

`yAxis.setLabelCount(19)`

This should give you labels from 0 to 180 in steps of 10, assuming you set min to 0 and max to 180.

Comment: Is not there any other way to set steps of value? this way works but knowing min and max values is needed. I mean for using this way setting min and max values is needed, but without knowing them?

Comment: any luck with the newest version ?